# Doubt regarding transitions in Time Dependent Perturbation Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

In Time-Dependent Perturbation Theory, One deals with the problem of transition from an initial state that is part of a discrete spectrum, to a continuum of states, now certainly the state space of the system is not changing, then how is it possible that at some time we have a discrete basis(before the perturbation is turned on)and then it becomes continuum basis?

Comment: What's an example of this? The closest thing I can think of is coupling one system with a discrete spectrum to another system with a continuous spectrum.

Comment: Extremely sorry sir, but could you please elaborate a little?

Answer (score 0):

There's a misunderstanding here. As you say, the state space doesn't change throughout this process. However, Hamiltonians can have spectra that have both discrete and continuous parts. For example, in a finite square well, there are both bound and free eigenstates. The bound states have energies corresponding to the discrete part of the spectrum, while the free states correspond to the continuous part of the spectrum.